# Can't uninstall application with long click

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, onlongclicklistener

I get an error in my listview using long click to uninstall an application display in this listview. The code is this:

```
protected boolean setOnItemLongClickListener(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onItemLongClick(l, v, position, id);// Error

        ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);

        Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:"+app.packageName);
        Intent uninstallIntent =
          new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageUri);
        startActivity(uninstallIntent);

        return true;
    }
```

the error is : `The method onItemLongClick(ListView, View, int, long) is undefined for the type ListActivity` How can i solve? i've already implements the `OnLongClickListener`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call the listener from your listView directly

```
yourListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "delete item in position : " + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> i've already implements the OnLongClickListener

Change that to be `OnItemLongClickListener`.

Also change `protected boolean setOnItemLongClickListener` to be `@Override protected boolean onItemLongClick`.

Comment: and the `super.onItemLongClick(l, v, position, id);`?

Comment: @David_D: That should be fine once you have followed the instructions in my answer.